# amcharts vertical bar graph, labels are missing

Tags: angular, amcharts, amcharts4

In the attached graph, labels are shoen alternatively,
This seems to be a default settings of the amcharts, can we change and make all the labels to display.

attached screen shot for the reference
This is implemented using amcharts in angular code[image]

Comment: Can you provide the configuration code? I don't think this is default behavior

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue with the following property
xAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;

This will resolve the issue